# Apache Commons DBCP 2.x Stability in Production

Tags: database-connection, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp, pooling

I am working on a multi threaded batch program where I have to use embedded connection pooling, I cannot use server managed connection pool because I cannot deploy it as a app client as there are few restrictions in client side.

I thought of using Apache Commons DBCP2.x but after researching on this I found many stackoverflow and blogs where people posted about unsteadiness of Apache Commons DBCP. Although during my research I never faced any issues in DEV environment.

May be this question asked in many forums, I am confused and I really need expert suggestion on this

1) Is Apache Commons DBCP 2.x Stable for Production?

2) Shall I choose other connection pooling like c3p0, BoneCP etc...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 .DBCP2 is used in production. requires 'good' understanding of parameters to 'get it right' for the purpose.

2. c3p0 is big (as in number of classes), BoneCP is deprecated in favor of [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)

Hope this helps.